# Select portion of timeseries

Tags: matlab, time-series

In the code below I create a simple data series, a time vector, and then a timeseries. I have no problem plotting both of them. (It's not important that they are on the same plot.) What I haven't been able to figure out is how to subset a portion of a timeseries as shown by the last command that fails with the error:

```
>> timeseriesTest
Error using timeseries/plot (line 27)
The plot method can only be used for a single timeseries object

Error in timeseriesTest (line 14)
plot(ts(25:end));

>>
```

How do I extract the last 25 (in this case) values in the time series? IMPORTANT: While not true in the code below my timeseries have daily or weekly time stamps and I do need to preserve that. I.e.:

```
NewData = ts.data
```

...isn't a good answer unless it's the only way to get a new extracted timeseries.

```
t=[1:50];
d=sin(2*pi*t/20);

ts = timeseries(2*d, t);

%plot data and timeseries
plot(d);
hold on;
plot(ts);

figure();
plot(d(25:end));
hold on;
plot(ts(25:end));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the properties of a `TimeSeries` object, when you run your code before you try and plot, this is what we see:

```
>> ts

  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: 'unnamed'
            Time: [50x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [1x1x50 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]
```

You see that there is a `Data` field in your time series object, as well as a `Time` field that represents the time value at each point instance.  If you want to individually access the fields, and plot the last 25 elements, do something like this:

```
plot(ts.Time(end-24:end), squeeze(ts.Data(end-24:end)));
```

`ts` is your `TimeSeries` object, and if you want to access fields within this said object, use the dot operator (`.`... and you've already figured that out).  Once you use the dot operator, you simply access the field you want by using its appropriate name.  Therefore, if you want the time values, use `Time` and if you want the data, use `Data`.  Now, what may seem strange is that I used `squeeze`.  [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) removes singleton dimensions.  If you can see, `Data` is a `1 x 1 x 50` array, when it should really be just a `50 x 1` array.  The purpose of `squeeze` is to remove redundant dimensions to get our actual data.

Note that this only seems to happen if you only have one signal within your time series.  Should we have multiple signals... say, if we wanted three signals of length 50, we would create a 50 x 3 matrix where each **column** denotes a single signal.  It would look something like this:

```
>> t = 1:50;
>> A = rand(50,3);
>> ts = timeseries(A,t)

  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: 'unnamed'
            Time: [50x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [50x3 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]
```

---

[`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) generates a random matrix or vector of values of any size you want in the range of `[0-1]`.  You'll see that our signal is now `50 x 3`.  If you want to plot this, `plot` recognizes multiple signals per time frame.... so you can just do this:

```
plot(ts.Time, ts.Data);
```

This should generate a plot of three traces, each delineated by a different colour and within the same time frame specified by `ts.Time`.

Similarly, if you want to plot the last 25 points for each signal, simply do:

```
plot(ts.Time(end-24:end), ts.Data(end-24:end,:));
```

This code will access the last **25 rows** of every column (i.e. every signal) in your `Data` and plot them all.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng. If I could give you 100 points I would. Great answer and frankly one I was surprised not to find somewhere here on StackOverflow so I hope it gains you lots of points in the future.

Comment: @LGTrader - Thank you for your sentiments!  I'm frankly surprised this problem hasn't been addressed either and that I had to write an answer for it... weird!... but thank you nonetheless :)